# BI Publisher Properties Missing

Tags: oracle, properties, publisher

I can't seem to find anything related to this so hopefully you guys can help me out.

I recently had BI Publisher installed for me by our company IT. Usually i would prefer to do this myself (I'm a software engineer who worked tech support before), but company policy dictates that IT needs to install all company programs.

Anyways in BI Publisher I now have the issue that if i double click on a field i don't get the BI Publisher Properties as I should (Word 2007), instead I get the standard 'text form fields' properties. Is there anyway to fix this without IT getting involved since whenever I give them my laptop I end up being unable to work for quite a while.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your security settings have macros enabled.

If you had any older versions of BI Publisher desktop, that were not removed before installing the new version, you may have to remove both, and reinstall the version you want.

Make sure the version you are installing is compatible with the version of Word you are using. Oracle is really bad at compatibility.

Make sure you have a compatible version of Java installed too.

Do you see the add-in tool bar in the ribbon?